# Spark Reduce by Keys taking lot of time on Digital Ocean 2GB - 2core

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing following code on spark python. The idea is to concatenate list of values for keys in the sortedData rdd. However this simple process is extremely slow on my Digital Ocean system.

```
rdd1 = lines.map(parsecsv)

thanks  = rdd1.filter(lambda (x,(y,z,a)):'Error' in a ).map(lambda (x,(y,z,a)) : (x,1))

def reduction(x,y):
    return x+y

sortedData = thanks.join(rdd1).map(lambda x: [x[0],[x[1][1][0],x[1][1][1]]]).reduceByKey(reduction)
```

rdd1 has 3 million entries file size is 400mb.

thanks rdd has only 17000 entries.

However task 22 in reducebykey job is running for 52 minutes now and has processed only .4 million keys till now. How can i speed up this :( as this way slower than what python would have done. Also i am running this on localhost single system.

```
21  63  0   SUCCESS NODE_LOCAL  driver / localhost  2016/03/19 07:15:46 3 s     4.1 MB / 207    5 ms    190.5 KB / 2    
22  64  0   RUNNING NODE_LOCAL  driver / localhost  2016/03/19 07:15:47 52 min  0.3 s   5.0 MB / 206        0.0 B / 0
```

--------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------

I got this working faster.
However while analysing my rdd thanks i found out that it has some duplicate values , so i added one line of code to remove duplicates from the rdd

```
thanks  = rdd1.filter(lambda (x,(y,z,a)):'Home:Your order has been received' in a ).
map(lambda (x,(y,z,a)) : (x,1)).*reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x)*
```

After adding the reducebykey the thanks rdd size reduced to 10k from 17k.
But strangely now the whole data got processed in 10 minutes. Can someone explain me how does duplicate keys can be causing that much trouble ?

Comment: First of all don't use `reuceByKey` when you mean `groupByKey`. There is nothing to gain in PySpark, and quite a lot to loose on JVM. And if you have data that can be processed on a single tiny machine and you need speed don't use Spark. It is not designed with cases like this in mind and such restricted resources are barely enough to handle Spark core processes alone.

Comment: This is just one day sample file. I need to process this data for 1 year. Hence not possible on one single machine. Also if spark is going to take this long to compute this how can i find out how many nodes should i use to process this.  Also the reducebykey is still running for 3 hours now '22 64 0 RUNNING NODE_LOCAL driver / localhost 2016/03/19 07:15:47 3.1 h 1 s 5.0 MB / 206  0.0 B / 0'

Comment: Any reason you're mapping, filtering and then mapping again? Why not a single map and then remove the erroneous elements? Also, if you expect to process millions of lines locally, don't expect any speed up, Spark isn't meant to be used like that. You're better off with manually doing. Or, actually run Spark on a decent cluster that can speed up your computations

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I need to find certain keys from the file and then perform self join to get details only for those keys. Thats why i did join map filter and then map again. The last map is to remove redundant data from the rdd before the join.  But thanks for your response :).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others suggestions that probably 2GB machine is a bit small but there is definitely something that you can do to speed up your joins. It is called broadcast join. Take a look at broadcast variables at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables. Since your "thanks" rdd is small enough to fit in memory you can broadcast that rdd so that every node will have a local copy of it in memory and the join will be much faster.

Comment: Can broadcast variable be of any help on single node ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that. Maybe not. But still there is not much you can optimize with 2GB machine. You should either scale up (bigger machine) or scale out (more machines)

Comment: As a suggestion I would try partitioning instead of keeping everything is a single partition and broadcast variable. If that doesn't work there is not much you can do.